# Inconsistent counter value when used in multi-threaded program

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm doing an assignment in C where we have a narrow road that can only support up to three cars at a time. The road is one-way so cars are allowed to go either East or West. Starvation should also be avoided. My implementation so far seems to work generally but I'm having a hard time understanding why the `numOfCarsOnRoad` variable has inconsistent values (i.e. printing 'Number of cars on the road = 1' twice in the output instead of '.. = 3', '.. = 2', '.. = 1') despite each thread incrementing/decreasing it each time.

Furthermore, I've noticed that if for example three threads "start" one after another (thus calling sleep(1)), they may finish in a different order. I understand that each thread runs in a separate lightweight process but shouldn't the sleep(1) last shorter for the thread that went first? Is there a way to avoid this?

The number of cars (represented by threads) is passed via the cmd args (i.e. '-c 5').

header:

```
void * crossBridge(void *i);
void parseCarArg(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "ask2.h"

sem_t sem;
int numOfCarsOnRoad = 0;
int carsGoingW = 0;
int carsGoingE = 0;
long numOfCars = 0;       // used for thread initializations
char currActiveDir = '_'; // either W or E ( _ initially)

void *crossBridge(void *i)
{
    int id = *((int *)i);
    char direction[5];
    if (rand() % 2 == 0) {
        strcpy(direction, "West");
        carsGoingW++;
    }
    else {
        strcpy(direction, "East");
        carsGoingE++;
    }
    if (currActiveDir == '_')
        currActiveDir = direction[0];

    printf("Car #%d waiting to pass to the %s...\n", id, direction);
    while (currActiveDir != direction[0] || numOfCarsOnRoad == 3)
    {
        sleep(2);
    }
    sem_wait(&sem); // enter critical region
    numOfCarsOnRoad++;
    printf("Car #%d going to the %s. Number of cars on the road = %d\n", id, direction, numOfCarsOnRoad);
    sleep(1);
    numOfCarsOnRoad--;
    sem_post(&sem);
    printf("Car #%d crossed to the %s! Number of cars on the road = %d\n", id, direction, numOfCarsOnRoad);
    if(direction[0] == 'W') carsGoingW--;
    else carsGoingE--;

    // helps to avoid starvation
    if (numOfCarsOnRoad == 0)
    {
        if (currActiveDir == 'W' && carsGoingE > 0)
            currActiveDir = 'E';
        else if (currActiveDir == 'E' && carsGoingW > 0)
            currActiveDir = 'W';
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void parseCarArg(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-c") == 0)
        {
            if (++i < argc && strlen(argv[i]) > 0)
                numOfCars = strtol(argv[i], NULL, 10); // convert to long
            if (numOfCars == 0)
            {
                perror("You must enter a number of cars > 0!\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 0)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    parseCarArg(argc, argv);
    srand(time(NULL)); // seed the generator using epoch time in millis

    if (sem_init(&sem, 0, 3) == -1)
    {
        perror("Failed to initialize semaphore!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pthread_t cars[numOfCars];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numOfCars; i++)
    {
        if (pthread_create(&cars[i], NULL, crossBridge, &i) != 0)
        {
            perror("Failed to create threads for the cars!\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    // wait for all threads to finish
    for (i = 0; i < numOfCars; i++)
        pthread_join(cars[i], NULL);
    sem_destroy(&sem);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you call `pthread_create(&cars[i], NULL, crossBridge, &i)`, why do you think the value in `i` will stay the same?  `int id = *((int *)i);` gets whatever the **current** value of `i` happens to be, not what it was when `pthread_create()` was called.  If the `for` loop that called `pthread_create()` has ended, `i` doesn't even ***exist*** any more.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I initially worried about that but it never (seemingly) caused me any issues in the output so I skipped it. I'll correct that as well!

Comment: You access `numOfCarsOnRoad` both inside and outside of a critical section. That is a data race, with undefined behavior. _Any_ (non constant) data shared by threads _must_ be protected by a mutex.